# html Table, how to make top column just fit the height of the content with column below taking up the rest

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

Stuck using a table layout like this below with a lot of content in column a and all the columns with a set width and with vertical-align:top

```
    ----------------------------------------------
    |       |                          |         |
    |   a   |         b                |    c    |
    |       |                          |         |
    |       |                          |         |
    |       |                          |         |
    |       |--------------------------|         |
    |       |    d        |     e      |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

I have a code example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cwQtK/

and I need it do this where column b is just as tall as the the content so it looks like the content in columns d and e are coming directly after the content in column b.

```
    ----------------------------------------------
    |       |                          |         |
    |   a   |         b                |    c    |
    |       |--------------------------|         |
    |       |     d       |      e     |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    |       |             |            |         |
    ----------------------------------------------
```

I can kind of hack it to do what I want in Firefox (and Chrome out of the box does it the way I want) by setting the height of column b to less than the size of it's content.

http://jsfiddle.net/cwQtK/1/

The problem is this doesn't work in IE.

Anybody know how to do this type of layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make b,d, and e a separate table without a set height, then it will auto shrink to the content. So you will have one table, a,b,c then inside that b cell you will put your current b,d,e

Comment: Thanks, works great! I wish you didn't have to nest tables but I'll do what I got to do